# Javascript disabling my postback

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have an ASP.NET checkbox, and I want to run some javascript before it posts back.

Something like:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelected" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelected_CheckedChanged" />
```

but I want to run a JS confirm dialog when the user click it, and if they were UNCHECKING it, I'd like to ask them if they're sure, and if so, postback and run my serverside code. If they say No, don't postback at all.

Anyone know of an 'easy' way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `onclick` handler:

```
<asp:CheckBox ... onclick="if (!this.checked && !confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;" />
```

(I believe this will work, but I didn't try it)

You can also add an event in Javascript.  (which is more likely to work)
Using jQuery:

```
$('#<%=chkSelected.ClientID%>').click(function() {
    return this.checked || confirm('Are you sure?');
});
```

Comment: But this doesn't cause it to postback does it? I need it to just do nothing if they click No, and if they click Yes it should cause a postback and run my serverside 'checked changed' event. Which I think requires it having the '__doPostBack()' method in the onclick method.

Comment: If the handler returns true, it should postback from the inline handler.  Try it.

Comment: yep that did it! I'm a little confused as to why though...
Your JS: if (!this.checked && !confirm('Are you sure?')) return false; will cause a postback if they click Yes, and no postback if they click No.
My JS: return confirm('Are you sure?'); will never cause a postback no matter what you choose.
Why is this?
Thanks either way!

Comment: By writing `return ...;`, you're exiting the `onclick` handler before ASP.Net's `__doPostBack()` call (which comes right after your `return` statement).  You should only `return` at all if you want to suppress the postback.  Look at the generated source in the browser.

Comment: That's what I would have thought, but while I was waiting, I went another route and used an ImageButton control. I set OnClick="ibSelected_Click". Then in the Page_Load i put this:
ibSelected.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure?');";
and what shows up in the generated source is this:
<input type="image"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(...etc. which works, Click Yes->postback, Click No->no postback.
I'm surprised that this works.

Comment: That's because the default behavior of an `<input type="image">` is to submit the `<form>`.  However, an `<input type="check">` will not submit the `<form>` automatically. (Unless the Javascript handler submits it manually)

Comment: Good to know. What I don't know about JS could fill SO. On that note I just ordered Javascript the Good Parts from amazon; it came pretty highly recommended on here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this with a checkbox but try to see if there is an OnClientClick attribute for your asp:CheckBox. If there is, put the name of the javascript function in it. Then in your javascript you can `return true` if the postback should happen or `return false` if you want to cancel the postback.

Comment: Unfortunately no. That's only for Buttons, LinkButtons, ImageButtons etc. Which is too bad because that works exactly like what I want...

Comment: The other option I would think about is the JQuery code that SLaks posted.